# AngularJS square root

Tags: html, css, angularjs, square-root

I am making a simple calculator using HTML + CSS + AngularJS. Everything is working good, but i want to add a SquareRoot function. 
This is some code:

```
 function _solve(){
switch(_state) {
  case 'ADD':
    _total +=  parseFloat($scope.console);
    $scope.console = 0;
    break; //similar for the rest of the operations

$scope.add = function() {
    _solve();
_state = 'ADD';} //this is how i call the function.
```

This is my idea for Sqrt but i don't think is good:

```
$scope.getSqrt = function() {
$scope.console = (parseFloat($scope.console) * Math.Sqrt).toString();}
```

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/math_sqrt.htm can you not do something like this?

Comment: While it's possible to inject Math to use with Angular, it isn't the Angular way of dealing with the problem. In Angular, you would make your own square root function (using Newton method would be the best)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the number you wish to extract the square root from to the `Math.sqrt()` function as an argument such as:

```
Math.sqrt(parseFloat($scope.console).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Math.sqrt is a function, which means you need to put the number you wish to apply the function to inside brackets like so

```
Math.sqrt(parseFloat($scope.console)).toString();
```